# Local Notifications set specific fire date

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification

Im making an iOS app that features local notifications. What I want to do is set the fire date for a local notification to a specific date. For example: The notification will go off on July 28th 2014 at 10:31 AM.

```
[localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
```

That is what I have now which sets the fire date for 10 seconds after the app launches. So how to I set it to an exact date?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a date from components like this:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.minute = 31;
dateComponents.hour = 10;
...
NSDate *fireDate = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

Comment: Just to add, you must use 24 hour time.